# Create a simple VPN in Azure

Tags: azure, vpn, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

TLDR;
I got Azure credits, how do I make a simple VPN?

I recently got some Azure credits through a hackathon. How do I create a simple VPN on Azure. It need not be too feature rich, **I just wanna use it to access blocked or region specific websites**.

I saw on Azure portal that there is virtual machine and virtual network. I don't exactly need a VM, just want to redirect all network traffic through the virtual network.

How do I do this in Azure, Has anyone done anything similar in Azure?

Free VPN are slow and have bugs and paid VPN are expensive & I would like to use my azure credits to create my own VPN.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use Azure VPN similar to a consumer VPN like ExpressVPN or NordVPN which protects your client while you surf the Internet.  Azure VPN is **not designed to be used to surf the Internet**.  Azure VPN is a service that allows you to create a secure Site-to-Site or Point-to-Site VPN into an Azure Vnet.  This allows you to communicate securely with resources in Azure without exposing them with a Public IP.

A VPN gateway is a specific type of virtual network gateway that is used to send encrypted traffic between an Azure virtual network and an on-premises location over the public Internet. You can also use a VPN gateway to send encrypted traffic between Azure virtual networks over the Microsoft network